# form preview page before submitting to database using asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, preview

I wan to create a form preview page where before the user submit its form to the database, the user can preview the form first by clicking the preview button.

Can anyone give me any idea how to do it or any sample codes using C# and asp.net that I could refer on?

Thanks

Comment: You can save form's data in a session and then display accordingly when preview button is clicked. Same as we create a shopping cart and display all products of the cart to the customer before checkout, which is done using a session.